# disabling streams in quicktime movies with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime, audio

In Quicktime pro you can turn off streams in movies, without deleting the stream. Is it possible to do this with a command line application like ffmpeg?

I have a bunch of video files that were recorded with both the crappy on-camera mic and a separate audio recorder. I've synched the sound and added it to the video, and now each clip has two audio streams. I want to keep the original audio, for reference and archival purposes but disable it. It's obviously done in metadata, but can it be done by ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

[QTCoffee](http://www.3am.pair.com/QTCoffee.html) let's you edit track information in QuickTime files, but it's OS X only and donationware:

```
$ modmovie -list clip.mov
Track list for clip.mov:
    * Video Track
    * Timecode Track
    * Sound Track
$ modmovie -disable "Sound Track" -save-in-place clip.mov
```

If you are on OS X, and if you have QuickTime Pro (included in the pro apps), I would rather use that and AppleScript.

For other platforms: [libquicktime](http://libquicktime.sourceforge.net/) can also [edit track properties](http://libquicktime.sourceforge.net/doc/apiref/group__atoms.html) through it's API, so you will need to write a command line wrapper first ...